# How to calculate a complicated permutation?

Tags: permutations, combinations, factorial, random

I'm writing a play that features a lot of randomization, which will mean that it is different every time, and I'm trying to calculate the number of performance possibilities.

- It features a number of scenes, which will be performed in a
  different order each performance.
- The roles within each scene are to be played by different actors each
  time.
- The cast size is also variable!

So there are X amount of scenes, Y amount of roles within the scenes, and Z amount of actors to be filled in each role. (For example: 38 scenes, with 77 total speaking roles to be divided among 9 actors.) The speaking roles would ideally be evenly distributed among the actors.

How would I calculate the number of performance possibilities this play can hold?

Hopefully I'm making myself clear! Thanks for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this data

> $38$ scenes, with $77$ total speaking roles to be divided among $9$
>   actors

there are $38! = 5.23 \times 10^{44}$ orders for the scenes, even before assigning actors. That's more than $5$ followed by 44 $0$'s.

For convenience estimating, I'll work with $72$ rather than $77$ roles, since that's a multiple of $9$ - each actor will get $8$ roles. There are $72!/(8!)^9 \approx 2.2 \times 10^{62}$ ways to assign the roles.

When you multiply those together you get a number with more than $109$ digits. A googol has a mere $100$ zeroes. This is about a billion googol.

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense to me! (Also, wow!)

Comment: Is there a way to calculate this for if there is an UNEVEN amount of actors? i.e. certain actors would have more roles than others if the number doesn't divide easily? Obviously, you can't give an actor 2.56 roles or whatever...

Comment: Yes. The formula is a little more complicated. You give out as many as fit in evenly and then count the number of ways to divide up the extras. Do you really need to know?